# VS2010 - WinForms - DataGridView - Binding to DataSet

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I am new to winforms and I have a datagridview inside a table control.
I am trying to bind it to display data.

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add("Results");

dataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");

dataTable.Rows.Add("1","Jack");
dataTable.Rows.Add("2","Donna");

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
```

I don't find a dataGridView1.DataBind? So I am wondering how I can achieve this?

Also, I'm trying to figure out how to have the first column of the DataGridView as a checkbox. any pointers would help.

Comment: I apologize! Thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-bind-dataset-to-datagridview.html

This should help with your databinding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx

take a look at that for the checkbox column

Here is some sample code

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Blah",typeof(bool));
        dt.Columns.Add("Blah2");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

As of note, the link BWC's answer gives off incorrect syntax for referencing a datatable from a dataset. You use []'s not ()'s to reference the index of datatables in a DS.

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add("Results");

dataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");

dataTable.Rows.Add("1","Jack");
dataTable.Rows.Add("2","Donna");

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["dataTable"]
```

If you are looking at checkboxes, but not one that is boundto any data, use the property editor of the DataGridView to edit the columns (click on the elipses "..." in that field)

Click on Add, select unbound column, and finally choose the checkbox column type:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Setting DataSource property will bind datasouce. ASP.NET needs a .DataBind call instead.

For the checkbox you need to add a column of type DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.

Best resource i found on databind (these are for framework 2.0/VS2005):

- http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/Data%20Binding/DataBinding%20FAQ.doc
- http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc

Answer (score 0):

you only have to add this:

dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables(0).ToString()