# GUI on windows to manipulate records in an SQL server db?

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, user-interface

I would like to make a very simple GUI (.exe) on windows so that users can manipulate a particular record in an SQL server db. It is a large database and I only want to make one record (used as a flag) available to clients for manipulating. What is the best way to create a simple GUI and connect it to an SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` control, and bind it to a `System.Data.DataSet`.

There are PLENTY of sources on the web to get you started (have you tried Googling this first?), e.g. 
[VS2010 - WinForms - DataGridView - Binding to DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154839/vs2010-winforms-datagridview-binding-to-dataset) and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07c74036-6448-4fbd-a8c1-98846a1b8a61/filling-datagridview-from-dataset-table.

Here's a simple example of how to do this in VB.NET:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = GetSQLDataSet("SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE [MyIDValue]=@IDValue",
                                             String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True", "DatabaseServerName", "MyDatabase"),
                                             New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IDValue", 12345)).Tables(0)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Run a SQL query with the provided information, and return a <see cref="DataSet"/> with any records returned by the query.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="forQuery">The string SQL query that will be run.</param>
''' <param name="withConnectionString">The connection string for the SQL data connection.</param>
''' <param name="withParameters">A collection of zero or more parameters to be used with the query.</param>
''' <returns>A <see cref="DataSet"/> containing any records returned by the query.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Shared Function GetSQLDataSet(ByVal forQuery As String, ByVal withConnectionString As String, ByVal ParamArray withParameters As SqlClient.SqlParameter()) As DataSet
    GetSQLDataSet = New DataSet()

    Using conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(withConnectionString)
        Using command As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(forQuery, conn)
            command.Parameters.AddRange(withParameters)
            conn.Open()

            Using dataAdaptor As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command)
                dataAdaptor.Fill(GetSQLDataSet)
            End Using

            conn.Close()
            command.Parameters.Clear()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I did try googling this before, but I am totally new to .NET and couldn't find much.

Comment: @CheckMateNinja -- You're welcome.  I would suggest adding tags to your question to indicate that you were intending to do this in .NET (if, in fact, that is true).